# Rest API content language negotiation

Tags: rest, api, standards, multilingual

I'm currently building an API where developers will be able to call and request a specific language thru the header. But I'm also developing an API client for the administrator (kind of alike a CMS).

For that client, I would like to be able to return all the available locales in one call.

So for example, an API public call (`language=en`) would return the following:

```
{
    name: 'Steve',
    description: 'My english description',
    url: 'http://example.com'
}
```

But I would also be able to make a multilingual call to get the data for all locales:

```
{
    name: 'Steve',
    locales: {
        en: {
            description: 'My english description',
            url: 'http://example.com'
        },
        fr: {
            description: 'Ma description en français',
            url: 'http://example.com/fr'
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any REST standard to achieve this and avoid having to make 2 API requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend something like

```
GET /users/steve

{
    "name": "Steve",
    "description": "My english description",
    "url": "http://example.com"
}
```

with `Accept-Language` header set as `en` and

```
GET /multilang/users/steve

 [
     {
          "lang": "en", 
          "content": {
               "name": "Steve",
               "description": "My english description",
               "url": "http://example.com"
          }
     },
     {
          "lang": "fr",
          "content": {
              ...
          }
     }
 ]
```

to get all versions in all languages. A big advantage of this solution is that you keep an original structure of the resource (you just nest the original one in `multilang` resource) - it does not change its structure depending on lang header - that would be messy and inconsistent to get structure x with a language header, and structure y without the header on the same resource.

Other inspirations you may find [there](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/340469/192689).